# VBA Paste Special on Existing Chart

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I would like to use VBA to paste a range of data into an existing chart, using the options shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

If I record a macro whilst doing so manually, the code only states `ActiveChart.Paste`. Thus, when I re-run this code the series is pasted regularly without the 'Series Name In First Row' deactivated. How can I code this correctly? I haven't found much in the way of help in my research so far.

Comment: I think you need to access the SeriesCollection Object.
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195817(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: @L42 Thanks, but it would appear as if this methodology is different in Excel 2010 as I can't get the expression.Paste(Rowcol,SeriesLabels,CategoryLabels,Replace,NewSeries) code to work. Would it make sense that this has switched to a Selection.PasteSpecial method syntax?

Comment: Nope. I don't think so. See my example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried a simple code and it works.
Suppose you have a data like below and you made a simple Clustered Column Chart:

[image]

Now you want to paste special *Data2* as in your screen shot.
VBA code which works at my end is below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ch As Chart: Set ch = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Range("A1:A4,C1:C4").Copy '~~> you need to include the x axis labels when copying
    ch.SeriesCollection.Paste RowCol:=xlColumns, SeriesLabels:=False, _
        CategoryLabels:=True, Replace:=False, NewSeries:=True
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

I don't know what chart you're working on or how you want it constructed.
Above just shows how to execute *Copy and Paste Special* of data from a *Range* to an *Existing Chart*. HTH